# How to change shift group size of resource pool dynamically during simulation in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to use anylogic to model labor shortage in production. I have the workers set as a resource pool with the capacity defined using shift plan, defining the number of workers by different shift. I am trying to include a event module that changes labor capacity for each shift during the middle of simulation. However, anylogic showed me an error saying I cannot change shift group size dynamically. Is there any workaround to allow this to happen? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate the schedule within an event each time you need to perform a change.

AnyLogic's API explains this quite well, see https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fdata%2FSchedule_API.html (sample model or 'creating and initializing schedule programmatically on model startup')

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried using the schedule api. Though the problem I have is that schedule does not allow me to define value with a parameter. I have to enter actual integer number into schedule such as 8 am to 8 pm value 4, however I need to enter parameter in the value section, such as 8 am 8 pm ShiftSize1. Since I am running experiment that requires me to alter shiftsize in each experiment. I am not sure how to make shiftsize a changeable parameter instead of a defined integer.

Comment: If you code your schedule, you can add parameters, e.g. see the function void addInterval(int startDay, int startHour, int startMinute, int startSecond, int endDay, int endHour, int endMinute, int endSecond, V value)